# How to read .doc file?

Tags: android

I have a `.doc` file saved on my **sdcard**. I need to read the content of `.doc` file and show it in a `TextView`.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my mistake. You need to do this.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String extPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.Separator;
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open(extPath + "file.doc");
    String text = loadFile(inputStream);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtv);
    tv.setText(text);
}

public String loadFile(InputStream inputStream) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
    int length = 0;
    while () {
        b.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
    return new String(b.toByteArray(), "UTF8");
}
```

Comment: AssetManager is for accessing resources in your apk, not for accessing data on the SD card. The question seems to be more about extracting the plain text from a .doc file and displaying that in a text view, possibly with some basic formatting.

Comment: @hossaindoula I seems the while loop is faulty. What did you put in there?

Comment: your code is faulty , first you are not using your inputStream and second your while loop is missing the argument