# How to add ton of text (using TextView) to content (Android studio)?

Tags: android-studio

I'm just started to programming in android studio and need to add a ton of text, but if I just paste all the text in the text field of the TextView component, then I get a mess. Tried to insert in the code of .xml, correcting paragraphs, but all the same it turns out not that. Therefore, several questions arose:

1. What is the most correct way to add a ton of text to the content? (Please refer to the details)
2. How can I make the text inserted correctly, with paragraphs, etc.? (Ie so that they are observed)?

All of this question's about ton of text.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all your text in a .doc file, format it in the way you want, then in your code, you load this file and output it to your `TextView`.

You need to make sure you import this file as an asset in your project or either load it from the device storage.

Please check this SO post: [How to read .doc file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489376/how-to-read-doc-file)

And check this to see [How to import file to assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959290/how-to-put-true-type-font-file-in-assets-folder-in-android-studio/25959305#25959305)